# Given a Java ssh-rsa PublicKey, how can I build an SSH2 public key?

Tags: java, public-key, ssh-keys

I'm doing publicKey.getEncoded(), then appending "ssh-rsa" to the front, then base64 encoding it. Then I add the SSH2 header/footer. But it won't decode...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java public keys are encoded as a standard X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure.

SSH2 uses its own simple format. Base-64 encode the result of the `encode` method shown below, and affix the necessary SSH2 header and footer.

```
public static byte[] encode(RSAPublicKey key)
  throws IOException
{
  ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  byte[] name = "ssh-rsa".getBytes("US-ASCII");
  write(name, buf);
  write(key.getPublicExponent().toByteArray(), buf);
  write(key.getModulus().toByteArray(), buf);
  return buf.toByteArray();
}

private static void write(byte[] str, OutputStream os)
  throws IOException
{
  for (int shift = 24; shift >= 0; shift -= 8)
    os.write((str.length >>> shift) & 0xFF);
  os.write(str);
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19435226/3474) for converting the other direction, from OpenSSH to Java.

Comment: Do I need to do something similar if I needed to PEM encode the privatekey?

Comment: It depends on the application you want to inter-operate with. If you need the key only (not embedded in a certificate) in OpenSSL's format, yes, you need to find out what the format is (probably the modulus and public exponent in a similar format, maybe as an ASN.1 Sequence) and encode it yourself.

Comment: Been looking for hours for this code example.  THANK YOU!  Wish I could gift you a bunch more reputation points.  :)

Comment: It's possible to do in one or two lines and more generic (support DSA and other types too) with SSHJ: `byte[] b = new Buffer.PlainBuffer().putPublicKey(key).getCompactData()` and then base64-encode it using `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)`.

Comment: @RaulSantelices worked. I just had to add the `ssh-rsa` header to mine. ```return "ssh-rsa " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b);```