# How to generate ssh compatible id_rsa(.pub) from Java

Tags: java, ssh, public-key-encryption, openssh

I'm looking for a way to programmatically create ssh compatible id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files in Java.

I got as far as creating the KeyPair:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator;
generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
// or: generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
generator.initialize(2048);
keyPair = generator.genKeyPair();
```

I can't figure out however how to create the String representation of the PrivateKey and PublicKey in the KeyPair.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Given a Java ssh-rsa PublicKey, how can I build an SSH2 public key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588120/given-a-java-ssh-rsa-publickey-how-can-i-build-an-ssh2-public-key)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The key format used by ssh is defined in the [RFC #4253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt). The format for RSA public key is the following :

```
  string    "ssh-rsa"
  mpint     e /* key public exponent */
  mpint     n /* key modulus */
```

All data type encoding is defined in the section #5 of [RFC #4251](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4251.txt). string and mpint (multiple precision integer) types are encoded this way :

```
  4-bytes word: data length (unsigned big-endian 32 bits integer)
  n bytes     : binary representation of the data
```

for instance, the encoding of the string "ssh-rsa" is:

```
  byte[] data = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 7, 's', 's', 'h', '-', 'r', 's', 'a'};
```

To encode the public :

```
   public byte[] encodePublicKey(RSAPublicKey key) throws IOException
   {
       ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       /* encode the "ssh-rsa" string */
       byte[] sshrsa = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 7, 's', 's', 'h', '-', 'r', 's', 'a'};
       out.write(sshrsa);
       /* Encode the public exponent */
       BigInteger e = key.getPublicExponent();
       byte[] data = e.toByteArray();
       encodeUInt32(data.length, out);
       out.write(data);
       /* Encode the modulus */
       BigInteger m = key.getModulus();
       data = m.toByteArray();
       encodeUInt32(data.length, out);
       out.write(data);
       return out.toByteArray();
   }

   public void encodeUInt32(int value, OutputStream out) throws IOException
   {
       byte[] tmp = new byte[4];
       tmp[0] = (byte)((value >>> 24) & 0xff);
       tmp[1] = (byte)((value >>> 16) & 0xff);
       tmp[2] = (byte)((value >>> 8) & 0xff);
       tmp[3] = (byte)(value & 0xff);
       out.write(tmp);
   }
```

To have a string représentation of the key just encode the returned byte array in Base64.

For the private key encoding there is two cases:

1. the private key is not protected by a password. In that case the private key is encoded according to the PKCS#8 standard and then encoded with Base64. It is possible to get the PKCS8 encoding of the private key by calling `getEncoded` on `RSAPrivateKey`.
2. the private key is protected by a password. In that case the key encoding is an OpenSSH dedicated format. I don't know if there is any documentation on this format (except the OpenSSH source code of course)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also  found jsch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), a free library which offers this functionality.

Comment: it seems it would be simpler to use: MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(key.getEncoded()).

Comment: is there a way to programmatically convert the [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) generated ssh rsa-keys back to a format [Java Cipher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) can use for encryption? As far as I can tell [that requires openssh commands](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7473874/1020470). `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key_file  -nocrypt > pkcs8_key` but what if you don't have access to to openssh?

Comment: @MarkMikofski you should create a new question to give it a better visibility.

Answer (score 7):

[gotoalberto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540206/gotoalberto)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14582408/314104) (quoted below) for a different question works for both RSA and DSA keys:

> If you want reverse the process, i.e. encode a `PublicKey` Java object
>   to a Linux `authorized_keys` entry format, one can use this code:
>
> ```
>     /**
>      * Encode PublicKey (DSA or RSA encoded) to authorized_keys like string
>      *
>      * @param publicKey DSA or RSA encoded
>      * @param user username for output authorized_keys like string
>      * @return authorized_keys like string
>      * @throws IOException
>      */
>     public static String encodePublicKey(PublicKey publicKey, String user)
>             throws IOException {
>         String publicKeyEncoded;
>         if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("RSA")){
>             RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) publicKey;
>             ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>             DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
>             dos.writeInt("ssh-rsa".getBytes().length);
>             dos.write("ssh-rsa".getBytes());
>             dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getPublicExponent().toByteArray());
>             dos.writeInt(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(rsaPublicKey.getModulus().toByteArray());
>             publicKeyEncoded = new String(
>                     Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
>             return "ssh-rsa " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
>         }
>         else if(publicKey.getAlgorithm().equals("DSA")){
>             DSAPublicKey dsaPublicKey = (DSAPublicKey) publicKey;
>             DSAParams dsaParams = dsaPublicKey.getParams();
>
>             ByteArrayOutputStream byteOs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
>             DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(byteOs);
>             dos.writeInt("ssh-dss".getBytes().length);
>             dos.write("ssh-dss".getBytes());
>             dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(dsaParams.getP().toByteArray());
>             dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(dsaParams.getQ().toByteArray());
>             dos.writeInt(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(dsaParams.getG().toByteArray());
>             dos.writeInt(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray().length);
>             dos.write(dsaPublicKey.getY().toByteArray());
>             publicKeyEncoded = new String(
>                     Base64.encodeBase64(byteOs.toByteArray()));
>             return "ssh-dss " + publicKeyEncoded + " " + user;
>         }
>         else{
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException(
>                     "Unknown public key encoding: " + publicKey.getAlgorithm());
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Personally, I like @ymnk's answer more, even if gotoalberto's solution is more accessible.  Thumbs up for one of the most useful Java libraries!

Answer (score 4):

As Carsten has mentioned, JSch can generate those keypair easily.
Refer to its example, [KeyGen.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/KeyGen.java.html)

Answer (score 2):

The generic solution for any `PublicKey` type (RSA, DSA, etc.) is a one-liner using SSHJ:

```
byte[] b = new Buffer.PlainBuffer().putPublicKey(key).getCompactData()
```

and then encode using `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b)`.