# How to get a new EC2 instance to mount an existing volume on which there is a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, key-pair

Several months ago, I followed http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663 and got it all running. Then, my PC crashed and I lost the keypair (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949835/accessing-ec2-instance-after-losing-keypair) and could no longer access the instance.

I want to now launch a new instance and mount this MySQL/DB volume which is left over from before and see if I can get to the data on it. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You outlined the correct approach to this problem already, and the author of the article you referenced, Eric Hammond, has written another one detailing this very process, see [Fixing Files on the Root EBS Volume of an EC2 Instance](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root) - it boils down to:

- start another EC2 instance
- stop the EC2 instance you can't access anymore
- detach the EBS volume from the stopped instance
- attach the EBS volume to the running instance
- SSH into the running instance
- mount the EBS volume in the running instance
- perform whatever fixes necessary, i.e. adjust the `/var` permissions in your case

Please see Eric's instructions for details on how to do this from the command line; obviously you can achieve all steps up to the SSH access via the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) as well, removing the need to install the [Amazon EC2 API Tools](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351), in case they aren't readily available already.