# parse and read a public key in java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have a requirement to read a public key using java and parse it, to check its validity, exponent, modulus or whether its valid or not. I tried the below code, and having issues. Can you please help me finding a solution for this problem?

```
public static void getPublicKey(String key) throws Exception {

key = key.replaceAll("-----BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
key = key.replaceAll("-----END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
KeyFactory kFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", new BouncyCastleProvider());
byte pub_llave[] =  new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer( key ) ;
X509EncodedKeySpec spec =  new X509EncodedKeySpec(pub_llave);
PublicKey pubkey = (PublicKey) kFactory.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what issues are you having? any error?

Comment: @ftom2 - Yes. Below is the exception trace - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific
 at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence.getInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, just edit your question and add it.

Comment: ssh doesn't use X509 encoded public keys. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java.

Answer (score 3):

SSH keys are not X.509 keys, thus it cannot work (this way).

https://jsvnserve.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jsvnserve/sshd/PublicKeyReaderUtil.java shows a way how to parse SSH keys.