# How to get modulus and pubExp in java?

Tags: java, ssh, cryptography, rsa, ssh-keys

is it possible to retrieve the modulus and pubExp from a ssh public key such as the one below:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC9t1iUplXCsaamE3QPxiB4G1BTZHH4oK4Ti2pHgfOEDLsVWrhycX+f8GbNnRATONkGjoDH9WWku1Eibbd2qpSfRrYowVmE85tEqXrT1mjPMSXrdKrLa4a9NLgHtaROZPNTxkuBHjdQkfgMnId/ryUw3maj+kHW1lUEx+wpALyLNTNJP0RFgO72x47wNELvolcZttaSTqrncH1ClcY2WQ4kmfOvzAgo1sRtRolc/6k17Oeo7eQRWgT4IwjLS9hYnXNicCn5Hg313iryJJ6Zq/eR/ormM7t8LMH8479qzdxinSk3GNCCw3xRDzYD/zcLsAGKwUnA+0g0JUdxEzQpGMHr user@mc-s08347cdc1.local
```

I need to get these parameters somehow from the key above so i can execute the code below to generate and get the public key in java

```
RSAPublicKeySpec ks = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, pubExp);
RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(KeySpec);
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind to at least upvote or accept my previous answer, jonney?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the SSH keys use a format defined in [RFC 4253](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt). So you can simply base64 decode your data (e.g. using Apache Commons Codec library) and then parse the binary result yourself.

This is the output of your base64 decoded string (you may need to postfix 2, 3 or 4 '=' characters for the decoder to work, you need a multiple of 4 base64 encoded characters):

```
000000077373682D727361000000030100010000010100BDB75894A655C2B1A6A613740FC620781B50536471F8A0AE138B6A4781F3840CBB155AB87271
```

Now lets dissect that (first part is the four bytes length in Big Endian format):

```
00000007 7373682D727361 // "ssh-rsa" string in ASCII
00000003 010001 // public exponent, the fourth number of Fermat or 65537 in decimals
00000101 00BDB75894A655C2B1A6A613740FC620781B50536471F8A0AE138B6A4781F3840CBB155AB87271
```

Well that last part is the modulus. It is 129 bytes instead of 128 because the library seems to use signed integers. As the 1024 bit modulus always starts with a first bit set to one, you can be sure that there is a `00` valued padding byte to the left of the unsigned representation.

Happy coding, some info taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java).