# Java/Kotlin Output Ed25519 keypair as both JCE KeyPair instance and in OpenSSH format

Tags: kotlin, bouncycastle, openssh, jce, ed25519

I'm generating Ed25519 key pairs in my Kotlin app using the [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library and have two requirements that are easy to implement in isolation, but seemingly difficult to do in tandem:

- Provide the key pair as a [JCE `KeyPair` instance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html) for use with a third-party SSH library
- Provide the public key in OpenSSH .pub format for the user to copy and paste into a git repository provider such as GitHub (i.e. `ssh-ed25519 <encoded key> <comment>`)

I have two options for generating the keys using BouncyCastle, each makes only one of these requirements easy.

#### Generate directly using BouncyCastle generator

```kotlin
val generator = Ed25519KeyPairGenerator()
generator.init(Ed25519KeyGenerationParameters(SecureRandom()))
val pair = generator.generateKeyPair()
```

This gives me a key containing `Ed25519PublicKeyParameters`, which makes it super easy to get the OpenSSH .pub format using `OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil` provided by BouncyCastle:

```kotlin
"ssh-ed25519 " + toBase64(OpenSSHPublicKeyUtil.encodePublicKey(publicKey))
```

...but there is no obvious way to get to a JCE `KeyPair` from here. The BouncyCastle JCE implementation seems to use `BCEdDSAPublicKey` and `BCEdDSAPrivateKey` as wrapper classes for exactly this purpose, but their constructors are package-private.

#### Generate using BouncyCastle as a JCE security provider

```kotlin
Security.addProvider(BouncyCastleProvider())
val keyPairGenerator: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(EdDSAParameterSpec.Ed25519, BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
keyPairGenerator.initialize(EdDSAParameterSpec(EdDSAParameterSpec.Ed25519), SecureRandom())
val pair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
```

This gives me the JCE `KeyPair` I'm looking for, but no obvious way to convert it to OpenSSH .pub format. The answers in [this RSA-specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java) all only support DSA/RSA, or suggest libraries that also don't seem to be able to handle the Ed25519 keys. I have tried:

- Apache SSHD
- SSHJ
- Jsch

#### What I think I need

Any one of:

- A way to convert from BouncyCastle's `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` to a JCE `KeyPair`
- A way to get a `Ed25519PublicKeyParameters` instance from a `BCEdDSAPublicKey` wrapper so I can use BouncyCastle's OpenSSH utility method
- Another way to output a BouncyCastle generated Ed25519 public key from a `KeyPair` in OpenSSH format
- Another way/library to generate an Ed25519 keypair that will support my two requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hack using reflection (wrapped into getter of extension property), following way #2 (get a `Ed25519PublicKeyParameters` instance from a `BCEdDSAPublicKey`):

```kotlin
val BCEdDSAPublicKey.pubKey
    get() = BCEdDSAPublicKey::class.declaredMemberProperties
        .find { it.returnType.javaType == AsymmetricKeyParameter::class.java }!!
        .apply { isAccessible = true }
        .get(this) as AsymmetricKeyParameter
```