# How to create an OpenSSH compatible ED25519 key with Bouncy Castle?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, openssh, ed25519

How can you create an OpenSSH ED25519 private key that can be used for SSH? The goal would be to have a key file in the same format same like you would have in `.ssh/id_ed25519` for your OpenSSH client.

This is my current approach, which does not create a compatible:

```
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.ec.CustomNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.AsymmetricKeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PrivateKeyFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;

public class Test {
    static {
        Security.removeProvider("BC");provider
        Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    public static String createCurve25519PEM() {
        try {
            X9ECParameters curveParams = CustomNamedCurves.getByName("Curve25519");
            ECParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECParameterSpec(curveParams.getCurve(), curveParams.getG(), curveParams.getN(), curveParams.getH(), curveParams.getSeed());
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", new BouncyCastleProvider());
            kpg.initialize(ecSpec);
            KeyPair keypair = kpg.generateKeyPair();

            AsymmetricKeyParameter akp = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keypair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
            byte[] content = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(akp);
            PemObject o = new PemObject("OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", content);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PemWriter w = new PemWriter(sw);
            w.writeObject(o);
            w.close();
            Log.d("createCurve25519PEM", "key: " + sw.toString());
            return sw.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("createCurve25519PEM", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBTwIBAQQgA8BjYjSjUgM4PahSZQx3i9DWcEdGiGnBoA0tXCUENzKggeEwgd4C
AQEwKwYHKoZIzj0BAQIgf////////////////////////////////////////+0w
RAQgKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqmEkUoUQEIHtCXtCXtCXtCXtC
XtCXtCXtCXtCXtCXtCYLXpx3EMhkBEEEKqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
qqqqqqqtJFogrhmhuKCGtOAe3Sx3SNFMkj1Nfm18YbIp6cWifs7T2QIgEAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAABTe+d6i95zWWBJjGlz10+0CAQihRANCAARl0Kc+dO0Er1dpu6mh
/lZmTw3/DMKPLTzjosX2u7hQswV+U9o0WOYFd1JOqsGdkLfYuGmdZzWdk74dvV1O
+w5T
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

.. but is unfortunately not accepted by SSH.

Comment: This hints at a solution, but is in Kotlin and about public keys, which is a slighly different matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64814085/java-kotlin-output-ed25519-keypair-as-both-jce-keypair-instance-and-in-openssh-f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using "Curve25519" that way gives it to you in the *short Weierstrass* form used by X9; this is not usable for Ed25519, which is defined to use twisted-Edwards form. Moreover cramming it through JCA's unfortunate `ECParameterSpec` class gives the original X9-defined 'explicit' representation which is now obsolete and almost never used even for algorithms which *do* use Weierstrass curves. As a result the data you create is not correct for PEM type OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY; it is valid for OpenSSL's 'traditional' PEM type EC PRIVATE KEY, and *OpenSSL* (which does still support, though not prefer, "param_enc explicit") is able to read that content with *that* type, though it can't be used to interoperate with anything else.

You need to either use JCA with *algorithm* "ED25519" (not "EC" "ECDSA" "ECDH" "ECMQV" etc which are all X9/SECG) something like this:

```
    KeyPair pair = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ED25519","BC") .generateKeyPair();
    AsymmetricKeyParameter bprv = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(pair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
    // then proceed as you already have; I have simplified for my test environment
    byte[] oprv = OpenSSHPrivateKeyUtil.encodePrivateKey(bprv);
    PemWriter w = new PemWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    w.writeObject(new PemObject("OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY", oprv)); w.close();

    // BTW if you pass an actual Provider to .getInstance (rather than a String, or letting it search)
    // you don't actually need to have put that Provider in the searchlist
    // Also in Java 15 up you can use the SunEC provider (normally searched by default)
    // but since you still need other Bouncy pieces why bother
```

or since you're already dependent on Bouncy use the lightweight API:

```
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator gen = new Ed25519KeyPairGenerator(); 
    gen.init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 255));
    AsymmetricKeyParameter bprv = gen.generateKeyPair().getPrivate();
    // ditto
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. In the end I used a specific library (sshlib) to avoid many pitfalls.